# rotated image inside <div> comes out of div block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have created two div and in second div i have attached an image and rotated it. But the image overlaps the content in first div.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUrq6.png)

Attaching and image for better explanation

```
.image1 {
height: 570px;
width: 350px;
transform: rotate(25deg);
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;}

.container-fluid { padding: 3% 15% 7%; }

.download-button {
margin: 5% 3% 5% 0%;
padding: 3%;}
```

//html

```
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Meet new and interesting cats nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-button"><i class="fa-brands fa-apple"></i>
        Download</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-button"><i
          class="fa-brands fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="cat-image">
      <img class="image1" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: share your code...without it, it is difficult to understand where you're doing wrong

Comment: It's better if you include the code too. You could use [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) CSS property.

Comment: Maybe try to add "overflow: hidden;" on the image container so it does not overlap

Comment: i have added the css which i have used for image and for div

Answer (score 2):

add a `overflow: hidden` property on second div

for example:

```
#cat-image {
  overflow-hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have tried overflow: hidden property in like all of the div, but it didnt work..

Comment: may be you are doing some syntex error check your css code. did missing any semi colons